# Customizing ASP.NET Membership Provider to add logging capabilities

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I need to slightly tweak the functionality of the ASP.NET Membership provider to add custom logging functionality.  Instead of creating a wrapper class around the methods I wish to modify, I was toying with the idea or creating a custom Membership Provider and override a few of the methods.

All the examples I could find would show how to create it from scratch.  I don't want to overwrite everything... just override a few methods.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

EDIT:
DOH!  I can simply inherit from SqlMembershipProvider and override the methods.  However, how can I get at the connection string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is it that you are trying to log?

If you simply want to monitor success and failure of authentication, [ASP.NET Health Monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx) is already in the box. Events are logged to the WebEvent tables.

If you have other motives, well then..... ;-)

---

to answer your question about the connection string, override `Initialize` and capture the value from the config argument before calling `base.Initialize`

Comment: Here are my requirements (not complete list): 1) Successful login, 2) Failed login, 3) Password change, 4) Password reset.  Not all of these will be covered by the overridden Membership class.